# TSQL Como puedo crear un campo que dependa de otro

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Tengo un problema en TSQL que no se como hacerlo, me explico tengo que crear un campo que coja la fecha de otro campo y le sume 3 años, hay alguna manera de hacer esto directamente en el campo sin insertarlo?

Comment: Por que no `select DATEADD(YEAR,3, GETDATE())`? reemplaza `GETDATE()` por tu campo

Comment: Si  es eso exactamente pero, si quiero que cuando se añada una linea este proceso sea automático? no se si me explico (Disculpa por no saber expresarme) .. Tendré que utilizar un TRIGGER o hay otra manera, Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 3):

Puedes definir una columna computada en la que definas la expresión de tu columna.  Por ejemplo, para crear una tabla con 3 campos, llave primaria, fecha y fecha_computada:

```
CREATE TABLE ejemplo (
    llave_primaria int not null,
    fecha datetime not null,
    fecha_computada as dateadd(year, 3, fecha)
)
```

En este caso, la columna `fecha_computada` está definida por la expresión: `dateadd(year, 3, fecha)`, que indica cómo se debe computar el valor de la columna a partir del campo `fecha`.

Opcionalmente se puede indicar que se *materialice* el resultado de la columna computada de tal manera que se pueda utilizar en un índice.  De otra manera, el resultado de la expresión no se guarda y se calcula en el momento que se debe proyectar en algún resultado.

Answer (score 0):

En SQL Server que yo sepa la única forma de hacerlo es mediante un trigger, pero como se trataría de un `UPDATE` a la misma tabla 
hay que tener en cuenta como funcionaría la solución, básicamente  lo que va a ocurrir es:

- `UPDATE/INSERT` de nuestra tabla

  - Ejecución del trigger

    - Nuevo `UPDATE` del campo que queremos actualizar automáticamente

      - Nueva Ejecución del trigger. Acá si no controlamos el nivel de anidamiento podemos entrar en un "loop", también podemos verificar si el nuevo campo ya fue actualizado

Que hay que tener en cuenta?

#### 1. El motor de la base de datos tiene que estar configurado para permitir transacciones anidadas.

Si es necesario, se podría hacer esto

```
ALTER DATABASE MiBase
   SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS ON;
GO
```

#### 2. Lo más importante es controlar el nivel de anidamiento del trigger

Para que no se produzca un loop de ejecución de triggers, usaremos la función `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()` y controlaremos que no supere las 2 ejecuciones, ya vimos que en un funcionamiento normal, el trigger se ejecutará dos veces.

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
    Id      INT IDENTITY,
    Fecha       DATETIME,
    Fecha3Meses DATETIME
)

GO

CREATE TRIGGER U_mytable ON dbo.MYTABLE AFTER UPDATE
AS

    IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) < 2)
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(Fecha)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE MYTABLE
                SET Fecha3Meses = DATEADD(MONTH, 3, I.Fecha)
                FROM MYTABLE T
                INNER JOIN INSERTED I
                    ON I.ID = T.ID
        END
    END

GO

CREATE TRIGGER I_mytable ON dbo.MYTABLE AFTER INSERT
AS

    IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) < 2)
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(Fecha)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE MYTABLE
                SET Fecha3Meses = DATEADD(MONTH, 3, I.Fecha)
                FROM MYTABLE T
                INNER JOIN INSERTED I
                    ON I.ID = T.ID
        END
    END

GO
```

Y para probar la solución

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (Fecha)
    VALUES('20170101')

SELECT * FROM MYTABLE

UPDATE MYTABLE SET Fecha = '20170201'

SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
```